# How to describe the feeling of resonance with everyone? For example, when you watch an eclipse with other spectators

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, nouns, phrase-requests

How do I describe the feeling of having a resonance with everyone? Like the way you feel when you watch an eclipse with everyone together. And it kind of give you the feeling of bravery, make you have the courage to do things you don't dare normally.

"A sense of _____ fills my heart when watching a solar eclipse, I feel like I can be better or braver."

I am asking this because I want to know is there an English word that can be used to describe this feeling. I am not an English speaker, so I don't have this type of word concept.

If you want to know what is my use for this word: I just want to know more words that can describe a feeling I have but cannot seems to find any word to describe it. Won't you want to know? When you truly think of it, can you speak of a word that can truly describe this feeling?

Comment: What research have you done to try to find an answer? There was a feeling of *kinship, camaraderie, fellowship, togetherness, esprit de corps, solidarity*, a *common bond* had been formed...

Comment: kumbuya ... oops that's a song

Comment: Reply to Jim: I have even asked on yahoo knowledge if you are wondering the extent of my research.

Comment: Edit your question to include an example sentence using this word.  Substitute "XXXX" or some such in the sentence where you'd like the word to fit.

Comment: Did you read the banner? It asks that you **include information about the word** you need. Now, you may think that the title covers everything but it does not. Why have you excluded "friendship", "happiness" or "feeling of resonance" for example? Resonance is a very good word, did you look in a thesaurus for words that have a similar meaning? If you want to know more words for happiness, the answer is [look up "happiness" in a thesaurus](https://www2.powerthesaurus.org/happiness) that link has nearly 200 suggestions!

Comment: Write a sentence where you would use this word or idiom  E.g. "Whenever I am with my friends gazing at the night sky I feel _____" OR "A sense of _____  fills my heart when watching a solar eclipse"

Comment: You still need a sentence where you would use this word. Similar to the ones I suggested above. You need to place this sample sentence near the top of your question, so it stands out and those users who review your question can see you made a significant change.

Answer (score 5):

You could talk about having a **communal experience** (like in this book title: http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/C/bo3623999.html)

On that note you could try using the word **communion** or the verb **to commune with**, but that could be hard to pull off. The word is very strongly associated with its primary meaning, which is the Christian ritual.

cf the fourth and fifth definitions on dictionary.com:

> 4. interchange or sharing of thoughts or emotions; intimate communication:
>      *communion with nature*.
> 5. the act of sharing, or holding in common; participation.

You could say everybody **felt connected**, or **as one**, or **in tune** with each other.

I don't think there is a specific word or expression for this feeling in English; when people describe this state they usually describe it with their own words and metaphors. In that context, "The feeling of having a resonance with everyone", or maybe rather "being in resonance with everyone", actually isn't that bad. I'd understand it, but then I have a maths/physics background and might not be the best judge.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough answer!! It provides me a lot of concepts in this aspect since I am not so familiar with difficult English words.

Comment: I like this answer. Another variant  : *Everyone felt a connection* or *there was a good vibe*.

Answer (score 1):

As we watched the eclipse with everyone together, **harmony** was restored.

> agreement in feeling, action, ideas, interests, etc.; peaceable or
>   friendly relations; agreement in action, opinion, feeling, etc; accord
>   [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/harmony)